# Swift iOS app for showing motivational quotes, with multiple screens

Tags: beginner, swift, ios, controller, cocoa

I'm one month into self-learning Swift, and I would like some advice to improve my coding skills.

*I have listed 2 situations that I think I need to improve*. I'd like some feedback focusing on my use of `static` variables for changing data between `ViewControllers` and `subviews`.

---

**1.0** Image 1 shows the app flow (Left = `HomeController`), middle = `MenuController`, Right = `FavouritesController`)

*Image 1* [image: Image 1]

In `HomeController` there is a `UIView` subview. From this subview the current quote (`HomeController.homeControllerCurrentQuote`) displayed can be saved to `favourites` array. This is a static array defined in `FavouritesController`.

The functions below are called from the `subview` within `HomeController`. I made `HomeController.homeControllerCurrentQuote` static because the subview needs access to it. Likewise for `FavouritesController.favourites`.

In `FavouritesController` the data contained in `FavouritesController.favourites` array is used to populate a `tableVIew`.

```
// FavouritesController.favourites is static variable!
// HomeController.homeControllerCurrentQuote is static variable! updated as user scrolls

func handleFavourite() {
    let favourites = FavouritesController.favourites
    if favourites.contains(HomeController.homeControllerCurrentQuote) { 
    removeFromFavourites()
    } else { FavouritesController.favourites.append(HomeController.homeControllerCurrentQuote)
        UserDefaults.standard.set(try? PropertyListEncoder().encode(FavouritesController.favourites), forKey:"myKey")
    }
}

func removeFromFavourites() {
    var tempArray: [Quote] = [.init(category: "", quote: "", author: "")]
    tempArray = FavouritesController.favourites
    let searchString = HomeController.homeControllerCurrentQuote.quote
    var filteredArray = [Quote]()
    filteredArray = tempArray.filter( { !$0.quote.contains(searchString) } )
    UserDefaults.standard.set(try? PropertyListEncoder().encode(filteredArray), forKey:"myKey")
}

// update static variable on HomeController
internal override func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
....
    HomeController.homeControllerCurrentQuote = Quote(category: cell.categoryLabel.text ?? "", quote: cell.quoteLabel.text ?? "", author: author)
....
}
```

Should I change how this is done? I don't like the use of static variables but as it's my first app I was more focused on getting it done rather than how it was done. Is it a good case for using a `delegate` and `protocol` to communicate between the views (I've never used this before)? If so how would I start to think about implementing it or, as it works, is what I've done satisfactory?

---

**2.0** When the app launches on `HomeController` required data is generated and is stored in a static variable.

```
                          //  [category : [quote  : author]]
static var xQuotesByCategory: [String   : [String : String]] = [:]
```

I make this data static because when I instantiate `HomeController` again from another controller, I don't want to have to refetch the data. I want to retrieve it once. Then when a new instance of `HomeController` is called I can make this check which should return false. Is this an appropriate use of a static variable?

```
if HomeController.xQuotesByCategory.values.isEmpty {
    ... fetchJson()
}
```

Following on from this, as `HomeController.xQuotesByCategory` is static, on `CategoriesController` I can call

```
var categories = Array(HomeController.xQuotesByCategory.keys)
```

This gets only the outer `keys` (categories) which I use to create the `collectionView` `cells` with the text and images shown in image 2. Again, same question, is this appropriate use of a static variable? Is there better way to ensure data is loaded only once and then pass the `keys` to `CategoriesController` in a different way when it's required?

[image: image 2]

---

If you'd like to try running the app, there is a test version available on TestFlight. Let me know and I can add you in TestFlight!